# Syntax error when creating stored procedure in DB2

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, db2

I am trying to create a stored procedure in DB2 which uses a cursor. However, I am having issues with the correct syntax and recieve the  error:

```
    SQL0104N  An unexpected token "=" was found following "N FOR SET v_party_id".  
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN".  LINE NUMBER=12.  SQLSTATE=42601
```

My procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Core.LWRH_LIST_CARRIER_EMAILS
(
    IN p_party_role_id BIGINT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN


DECLARE v_party_id BIGINT;
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SET v_party_id = (Select party_id from core.party_role where party_role_id = p_party_role_id);

Select cm.contact_method_id, cm.contact_method_type_id, cm.electronic_address
from core.party_contact_method pcm
join core.contact_method cm
on cm.contact_method_id = pcm.contact_method_id
and cm.contact_method_type_id = 6
and pcm.party_id = v_party_id;



OPEN c_result;

END@
```

Can anybody advise on what the correct syntax would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `SET` statement in the middle of your `DECLARE CURSOR` statement.  It should look like:

```
...

DECLARE v_party_id BIGINT;

-- This doesn't execute the statement, just declares the cursor.
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    select cm.contact_method_id, cm.contact_method_type_id, cm.electronic_address
    from   core.party_contact_method pcm
      join core.contact_method cm
        on cm.contact_method_id = pcm.contact_method_id
       and cm.contact_method_type_id = 6
       and pcm.party_id = v_party_id;


SET v_party_id = (Select party_id from core.party_role where party_role_id = p_party_role_id);


OPEN c_result;

...
```

Comment: Right okay, I thought that the statement was executed when the cursor was declared. That is why I did the set statement first as I thought the variables value would have not been set by the time it is used in the query. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that you do not define a cursor on a `set` statement.  You define it on a `select` statement.  So, this statement:

```
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
SET v_party_id = (Select party_id from core.party_role where party_role_id = p_party_role_id);
```

Doesn't make sense.

Try this:

```
DECLARE c_result CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    Select party_id
    from core.party_role
    where party_role_id = p_party_role_id;
```

Or, leave out the cursor, if there is only one row.

Comment: I have previously tried moving the cursor declaration to where you have suggested and I then receive the error: An unexpected token "<cursor declaration>" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "<SQL statement>